# While doing aggregation in MongoDB in lookup pipeline the id field is not available to perform match

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, lookup, aggregation

As mentioned I want to match tenant id while looking in the logs collection and I am aggregating over Tenants collection.

[image: without hardcoding tenant id]

But this gives logs as an empty array.
But when I did hardcoded the `tenant_id` then I get correct document with logs array

[image: with tenant_id hardcoded]

Where exactly I am wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the logs where the tenant_id (in the log schema) equals the _id from the tenant collection you called the aggregation on, you can define this in the lookup itself.

Example:

```js
const data = await db.models.Tenants.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'logs',
    localField: _id, // The field from this tenant
    foreignField:  tenant_id, // Has to match this field in logs
    pipeline: [{
      $match: {
        date: today().
        ...
      }
    }]

  }
}
])
```

Comment: where you got that _id field in the first place

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, I am assuming now that you have a tenant, and now want to lookup all the logs that contain that id? 
I will edit my answer for that scenario

Comment: yes I want logs for the tenant id... but I want to get tenant id in aggregation stage from current tenant document.. 
i.e - we are aggregating on the Tenant right. So I want tenant id from current tenant document that we currently aggregating on!